# Using a grid of points to detect if a object is in range

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of points and I made them using a for loop at the beginning of my app. Each point has two arrays,  one is named objectsAroundMe and the other is called pointsAroundMe.

The objective is to detect if the object is near the point (using for loop for both objects and points)

After detection then if the object is in range we push it to the point.objectsAroumdMe array.

I have all of this fine and working,  but the problem is getting the point to release the reference when the object is no longer near,  I've tried running  an if statement to do it and make the reference null but it doesn't work.  If there were an efficient way of doing this that made it so only one reference was moving from array to array then that would be perfect.  next I'm gonna try using array.splice and slice to copy amd paste references.  But for now I've tried using array.filter and indexof and findindex none worked.  But I'm newish to classes so if their is a difference between using a for loop iteration Id and using the"this" statement to clarify the object then please give me an example of how I would find the index of a "this" object and delete it's reference from the point array.

```
    onHitTest(){
                for (let ii = 0; ii < jsEngine.pointGrid.length; ii++) {
                    let point = jsEngine.pointGrid[ii];
                    let distanceBetween = calcTotalDistance(this.transform.x,this.transform.y,point.x,point.y);
                    let pointPosition = point.x + point.y;


         if (!point.objectsAroundMe.includes(this)) {
            if ( distanceBetween < mapWidth/density*1.4) {
                point.objectsAroundMe.push(this);
                this.hitTestArray = point.objectsAroundMe;
                this.pointArray = point.pointsAroundMe;
                //console.log(this.hitTestArray);
            } 


if(point.objectsAroundMe.includes(this)) {
                 if (pointPosition - distanceBetween > 100000) {
                     let indx= point.objectsAroundMe.indexOf(this);
                     point.objectsAroundMe[indx] = null;
                 }
             }
        }
            }
```

//// second for loop for hit testing the passed array from the point to the object.

```
        for (let i = 0 ; i < this.hitTestArray.length; i++){
            let hitTestObject = this.hitTestArray[i];
            if(hitTestObject.transform=== null)
                continue;
            if(hitTestObject === this)
                continue;
            let distance = calc_distance(this.transform,hitTestObject.transform);
            if (distance <  hitTestObject.transform.width + hitTestObject.transform.width
                && distance  <  this.transform.height + this.transform.height){
                //console.log("hit!")
            }

        }
    }
```

Mapwidth = 1000000 and density is 10.

distanceBetween: The distance between the object and the point using: return Math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2);

this = the object in question (to avoid double for loop)

pointGrid= a grid of points with a total of 90 points equally spaced by mapwidth/density

Comment: How about some code snippets?

Comment: The code is in separate locations and if I were to put all the code relevant to this here I'm afraid you would spend a bit of time looking through it. However if necessary I will submit it,  and I would have if it were not 12 am I am about to doze off and I plan to submit the code in the morning,  I appreciate your effort but I have to get some sleep if this did not screw with me enough today trying to make it work. *hits screen like 90's tech* *screen breaks like 2k tech* -_-'

Comment: We don't need to see all your code, but a small reprodusable example would be great. For loops to remove references is certainly possible, but not seeing any of your attempts that are failing it's really hard for us to help.

Comment: @keith   heres the code

Comment: @fatman - here is the code m8 , sorry for the delay guys

Comment: An aside: It would be nice if you would provide clean indentation on your code. Especially large code segments become much more readable. I'm not even sure where your first for loop is supposed to end without laboriously counting braces.

Comment: kk , just give me a sec here XD

Answer (score 0):

I found out after finally giving up on this technique after 2 weeks that it really was not performing as well as expected,  now I am going to take a similar approach and I will upload my code via: (functions and order of operation) shortly.